# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined angular 5

Tags: html, angular

I am new to Angular 5, I cannot seem to understand why my code is giving the above mentioned error. Please let me know where I am going wrong.
I have initialised all attributes of employee in my .ts file.

```
   <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group"
            [class.has-error]="name.invalid && name.touched"
            [class.has-success]="name.valid">
            <label for="name" class="control-label"> Full Name</label>
            <input required type="text" id="name" name="name"
             [(ngModel)]="employee.name" type="text"
                class="form-control"  #name="ngModel">
            <span class="help-block" *ngIf="name.invalid && name.touched">
                Full Name is Required
            </span>
        </div>
        <div>invalid: {{name.invalid}}</div>
```

Comment: use safe navigation operator `name?.invalid`  and `name?.touched` cause you code will try to access the property before the html is loaded completely

Answer (score 0):

Its important to post also your .ts content, but it looks like your are not initializing the name variable when your component loads. you might do this at ngOnInit like this:

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.name = new Foo();
}
```

Thats why the undefined error

Answer (score 0):

use safe navigation operator `name?.invalid`. Here is a working demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uv7qbb

```
<form>
   <div class="panel-body">
       <div class="form-group"
            [class.has-error]="name?.invalid && name?.touched"
            [class.has-success]="name?.valid">
            <label for="name" class="control-label"> Full Name</label>
            <input required type="text" id="name" name="name"
             [(ngModel)]="employee.name" type="text"
                class="form-control"  #name="ngModel">
            <span class="help-block" *ngIf="name?.invalid && name?.touched">
                Full Name is Required
            </span>
       </div>
       <div>invalid: {{name?.invalid}}</div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: may be you are missing the `form` tag

Comment: <form action="" #employeeForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveEmployee(employee)">

Comment: @KaushaniRC can you create a stackbliz , my answer seems to work fine in stackbliz

Comment: @KaushaniRC "cannot read property invalid of undefined" error will never occur if you use safe operator i.e. ?. Please try once again and share a stackblitz link for us to try.

Answer (score 0):

I think your employee object is null .
try :

```
 this.employee = new employee();
 this.employee.name = '';
```

In your .ts file

Comment: I have assigned all the attributes of employee to null in my ts file, still I have this error.

Comment: the error is not related to the model  object but ,he is trying to  access a property  before its defined